# Circle geometry, finding area of the minor segment

Tags: geometry, circles

Just need a little bit of help with this question:

[In the diagram below, the magnitude of the area of the minor segment cut off by chord AB is: (circle radius is 8, angle AOB is 105 degrees, don't know chord length.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sHaF.png)

I've tried manually solving it with the area of a segment formula (area of sector - triangle), and got $56\pi/3 - 32\sin(105)$, which is not the answer!
But I understand that area of the sector is $56\pi/3$, and triangle is $32\sin105$.
What is the question asking for?

Many thanks!

Comment: I agree with your answer. Maybe are you supposed to write as your answer $E-A$?

Comment: You have calculated the area of the sector and the area of the triangle right; I agree with you that $56\pi/3−32 \sin(105^\circ)$ is the answer. I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct. The given answer is wrong.

Minor segment area ( area difference between sector and triangle)

$$ =r^2 \theta/2 - r^2/2 \sin \theta $$
$$ =\dfrac {8^2 \cdot 105 \pi} {2 \cdot 180}-\dfrac{8^2\sin 105^{\circ}}{2}\text{
= what you got.}$$